# Ripple emulator out of vs 2013

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

I have installed apache cordova in vs 2013.

Operation system is windows 8 VM.

I try to run the `ripple emulator`.

The first time it is running but when I try even to close and run it again or leave it open and make changes and save to see the results it is only load the page.

Could be possible run the ripple emulator out of `vs 2013` but using the project I have created in vs? How can I make it?`enter code here`

Comment: Have you installed CTP3?

Answer (score 0):

CTP3 now has an "update on save" capability for Ripple that likely will solve your issue.

You can in fact run Ripple outside of Visual Studio using the copy of the source code in the bld/Debug folder after a build. Build for Android in the debug config, then go to the bld/Debug folder and execute the following from the command prompt:

```
npm install -g ripple-emulator
ripple emulate android --port 12345
```

A browser Window will appear. Paste that into Chrome if its not your default and retry. Note that you will need to move the contents of this folder back into the main project if you make edits.  CTP3 largely should eliminate the need to do this.